# Hosting multiple TileMaps

Tags: gdal2tiles, tile-map-service

I'm setting up this API that let's users upload high resolution images then generate tiles with those images using `gdal2tiles`. My question is what's the recommended way to host a tile map service? I am following these [steps](https://www.aubrett.com/article/information-technology/geospatial/tms-tile-service), but it looks like it expects me to update the XML files each time a new tile map is generated / uploaded.

Comment: can you code the xml updates? I don't have experience with this but I have automated publishing layers to geoserver which is xml format similar to the xml in the steps link you provided.